# getting url in wp_enqueue_style

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm having trouble getting the second argument in wp_enque_style. Here's how my site is setup:

- style.css
- custom_style.css
- index.php

In a template, I have this code:

```
$stylesheet_url = bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom_style.css'; 
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style', $stylesheet_url );
```

Which isn't working. Any reasons why?

The output is just the path to my template directory, outputted as raw text, which is obviously not the correct behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enqueue extra styles you should place the following code in your functions.php

```
function my_custom_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom_style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_custom_styles' );
```

Comment: To clarify: `get_template_directory()` (along with the OP's use of `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )`) returns the *file path* to the template directory. For publicly accessible resources (such as enqueued scripts/stylesheets), you need to use the template directory *URL*, which is returned by `get_template_directory_uri()` - and which this answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

use [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead, which returns the value instead of directly echoing it.